# Codeigniter - Get value from one DB Table and Add to other DB table on form submit

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter

Long story short, I am using Fullcalendar with Codeigniter. I am color coding the events in the calendar depending on the category of the event.

In Admin dashboard admin can add event category and provide name and color (from select menu). Hex value gets saved to database.

[image: event_categories_db]

When Admin adds an event, they add title, description, start, end and category.

Category option is a select menu from Event Categories, pulled from database.

When I add a new event, I want to use the event category name and grab its color and then store it with the event in the database in the last column like so:

[image: event]

Saving an Event:

I am using codeigniter form validation, and if all fields are validated I am trying to grab the color from the event category table and add it to the event in my $save_data array:

```
public function add_save()
{


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|max_length[500]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('start', 'Start', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('end', 'End', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required|max_length[1000]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'trim|required|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('has_attendance', 'Has Attendance', 'trim|max_length[1]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_recurring', 'Is Recurring', 'trim|required|max_length[1]');


    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

    // I am adding this to capture color from event_category table
    // 1. use the input category field from event 
    // 2. then I select all from event_category table
    // 3. WHERE name is equal to the selected category name from input
    // 4. The color is the reulting rows color field
    $selected_event_category = $this->input->post('category');
    $this->db->get('event_category'); 
    $this->db->where('name',$selected_event_category);
    $the_color = $this->db->get()->result()->row('color');


        $save_data = [
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'start' => $this->input->post('start'),
            'end' => $this->input->post('end'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'has_attendance' => $this->input->post('has_attendance'),
            'is_recurring' => $this->input->post('is_recurring'),
            'color' => $the_color //I have added this from above query
        ];

        $save_events = $this->model_events->store($save_data);

    } else {
        $this->data['success'] = false;
        $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
    }

    echo json_encode($this->data);
}
```

I have tried to do the query and store the result in a variable called $the_color. I am then using this variable in my $save_data array as the color value.

But the form will not post and I am not getting any errors. The event will not save, it does not go into the database at all.

I am hoping someone could possibly help point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I think you can use the row() method if you expect a single record from the database. Moreover, when you store data, you don't have to assign it to a variable.

Method in model file:

```
public function getEventCategory($selected_event_category) {
    $this->db->where('name', $selected_event_category);
    $q = $this->db->get('event_category');
    $q = $q->row();

    return $q;
}
```

And then in controller

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        // I am adding this to capture color from event_category table
        // 1. use the input category field from event 
        // 2. then I select all from event_category table
        // 3. WHERE name is equal to the selected category name from input
        // 4. The color is the reulting rows color field
        $selected_event_category = $this->input->post('category');
        $event_category = $this->Your_model_here->getEventCategory($selected_event_categor);
        $the_color = $event_category->color;

            $save_data = [
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'start' => $this->input->post('start'),
                'end' => $this->input->post('end'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                'has_attendance' => $this->input->post('has_attendance'),
                'is_recurring' => $this->input->post('is_recurring'),
                'color' => $the_color //I have added this from above query
            ];

            $this->model_events->store($save_data);

        } else {
            $this->data['success'] = false;
            $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
        }

        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
```

Another issue is you should pass your query to model. Codeigniter is base on the MVC model, so we should avoid using queries in the controller.

Comment: Hey KamS that worked perfectly! Thank you!! 
Also regarding putting this in the Model, I know exactly what you mean, but I didnt know how to execute this from the model: $selected_event_category = $this->input->post('category');

Comment: @BrianRevie I've developed my answer. I've added a method for a model and then received it in a controller